# How to send a notification when the app is closed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-service, android-notifications

I want a notification to happen whenever a child is added from my firebase database. I have the below code working within onChildAdded() while the app is running or in the background, but obviously not when it's closed. I read something about starting a service but was a bit overwhelmed.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mRecyclerView.getContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText("Content Text");

                Intent newAnimalIntent = new Intent(mRecyclerView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);

                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mRecyclerView.getContext());
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(newAnimalIntent);
                PendingIntent newAnimalPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(newAnimalPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NM.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the app is closed, your connection to the database may be closed, If you want to deliver messages to an app in that state, you should look at [Firebase Cloud Massaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

An example of this (combining the Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Cloud Messaging) can be found in this blog post: [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).