# Validity of listeners set in Firebase real-time users database on non-existing roots

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop contact book integration in my app.

To achieve it completed the part of adding account in Account and Sync using account authenticator service and AbstractAccountAuthenticator.

Also completed creating sync adapter and its service.

I am using firebase real-time database.

I am confused about the logic to be used to achieve sync when server data changes.
I have tried looping to all mobile contacts with SingleValueEvent listeners which is fired after detecting server data changes with addValueEventListener to the users node, but it is using much server data which might cost a lot.

So I thought of trying addChildEventListener to the users node,

```
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = firebaseDatabase.getReference(USERS_CHILD);
databaseUsers.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    Customer customer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("CUSTOMER_ID", customer.getId());
    bundle.putString("CUSTOMER_PHONE", customer.getPhone());
    bundle.putString("TYPE","ADDED");
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL,true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, bundle);
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Customer customer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("CUSTOMER_ID", customer.getId());
    bundle.putString("CUSTOMER_PHONE", customer.getPhone());
    bundle.putString("TYPE","REMOVED");
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL,true);
    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, bundle);
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

});

However, onChildAdded event checks for the entire child first then for the new addition. 
Application might have millions of user then checking each and every one is not a good practice and will use much server data.
The option I thought of creating multiple queries for each mobile contact and adding addChildEventListener to them, 
Now the question is that,

i.  What happens on querying on the non-existing root?

ii. For how long the listener will exists as the user might registered himself/herself days/weeks/months/years later and the respective event gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in bandwidth usage between using `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener`. Aside from that, I'm not sure I understand your questions. But I'll give it a stab.

When you attach a `ValueEventListener` on a non-existing node, your `onDataChange` will get called with an empty snapshot. If you attach a `ChildEventListener` on a non-existing node, none of its `onChild...` methods will be called.

If you attach a listener with `addValueEventListener` or `addChildEventListener` it will stay active until you either remove it, or until the app is closed.

Comment: The stab almost pierced through the question.

Now, if the listener gets deactivated as the app is closed (which will happen for sure) how to notify the app for new user registrations.

I was using periodic sync with all mobile numbers. It uses much server data which might cost a lot
(In the trial for one test user with 1000 mobile contact for a day. Usage reached 15mb approx)

I need a suggestion about the logic for the sync. 
So that it uses lesser server data for creating contact book integration similar to whatsapp (i.e. showing list of users of my app from contact book).

Comment: Is firebase going to create any such service (contact book integration. Invites much similar) in near future as you guys are already doing great job specially for the hobbyist like me.

Comment: What your describing sounds very specific, so it seems unlikely that there will be a service that does precisely that. Note that we're well into the land of new questions here btw. I'll try to quickly help, but you should really limit yourself to a single question per post.

Comment: For notifying users who have closed the app, you'll typically use FCM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622275/how-to-send-a-notification-when-the-app-is-closed You *could* put your listeners in a background service, but each new Android version clamps down more on those.